# how to create dynamically html form

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

When the user enter number like

```
int number=10;
```

Based on that number i need to create 10 html forms

I tried following code in jsp but it is not working in case of validation

```
<%   
int n1=10;
for(int i=1;i<=n1;i++)
{
%>
<form action="Store1.jsp" method="post" >

<pre>
Enter the First Name  :  <input id="FName" type="text" name="FName"> <br>
Enter the Middle Name :  <input id="MName" type="text" name="MName"> <br>

  <input type="button" value="Save" >  
  <input type="button"value="Edit" >  

</pre>      

<%
}
%>

<input type="submit" Value="Submit">
</form>
```

How can we create such html forms?? and provide validation to it??

Comment: Why you are defining only one Submit to 10 forms?
You have not closed the form tag: </form>

Comment: I think you're on the right track.  You just need to find the parts of the form that you need to be uniquely identifiable, and then do the same thing you did with the `name` attribute in your first `form` element.

Comment: At run time i m taking number from user it may be 10,20 any number in such case i don't know how to provide validation to html forms

Comment: If you haven't heard it, you should consider replacing your scriptlets with JSTL.

Comment: suppose user enter number=15 and when i tried to provide validation then it is applicable to only dynamically created first form because all the attribute are created with the same name...

Comment: what you are doing is correct(executable), but intent is not correct. why are you creating 10 forms with 1 submit button? You need to explain the requirement better.

Comment: i need to create html forms dynamically depend on the number user passing it may be 10, 20, 30, any number. Here i donot know how to create such forms and validate it.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<form action="Store1.jsp" method="post" >
<%   
int n1=10;
for(int i=1;i<=n1;i++)
{
%>
   <pre>
    Enter the First Name  :  <input id="FName<%=i; >" type="text" name="FName<%=i; %>"> <br>
    Enter the Middle Name :  <input id="MName<%=i; %>" type="text" name="MName<%=i; %>"> <br>

    <input type="button" value="Save" >  
    <input type="button"value="Edit" >  

   </pre>
<%
}
%>

<input type="submit" Value="Submit<%=i; %>" name="Submit">
</form>
```

you will have unique identifier for each field.
so basically you just loop through the fields, and check for `FName0, FName1, ...`